# wordpress site/home url has /#all tag suffix

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

i've tried this solution but to no avail, even on the function.php file:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/override-wordpress-site-url-with-wp-config-php

need to get rid of the #all tag on the home/site url on this site:
http://www.anthony-johnson.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I tried switching out your Javascript, and it looks like the problem could be somewhere in the file `/wp-content/themes/juiced/js/acad.min.js`. Unfortunately for you this is a massive gob of minimized Javascript and it's not easy to figure out what's going on in there.

You should really try contacting the author of this theme to find out what the problem is. All I can suggest is that you try changing the value of `includeAll` to `false` in this bit near the top of the file.

```
...{categories:true,categoryOptions:{includeAll:true,defaultCategory:false,...
```

(Or perhaps change `categories` to false?)